# Let the value of data to be the same in a time period in R

Tags: r

I have a question and does someone can help me answer it because I cannot find the method to solve it online.

If I have a data frame like this:

```
5/9/2017    9.96    NA
5/8/2017    9.77    NA
5/5/2017    10.57   NA
5/4/2017    10.46   NA
5/3/2017    10.68   NA
5/2/2017    10.59   NA
5/1/2017    10.11   0.91
4/28/2017   10.82   NA
4/27/2017   10.36   NA
4/26/2017   10.85   NA
4/25/2017   10.76   NA
4/24/2017   10.84   NA
4/21/2017   14.63   NA
4/20/2017   14.15   NA
4/19/2017   14.93   NA
4/18/2017   14.42   NA
4/17/2017   14.66   NA
4/13/2017   15.96   NA
4/12/2017   15.77   NA
4/11/2017   15.07   NA
4/10/2017   14.05   NA
4/7/2017    12.87   NA
4/6/2017    12.39   NA
4/5/2017    12.89   NA
4/4/2017    11.79   NA
4/3/2017    12.38   NA
4/1/2017    NA  0.9
3/31/2017   12.37   NA
3/30/2017   11.54   NA
3/29/2017   11.42   NA
3/28/2017   11.53   NA
3/27/2017   12.5    NA
3/24/2017   12.96   NA
3/23/2017   13.12   NA
3/22/2017   12.81   NA
3/21/2017   12.47   NA
3/20/2017   11.34   NA
3/17/2017   11.28   NA
3/16/2017   11.21   NA
3/15/2017   11.63   NA
3/14/2017   12.3    NA
3/13/2017   11.35   NA
3/10/2017   11.66   NA
3/9/2017    12.3    NA
3/8/2017    11.86   NA
3/7/2017    11.45   NA
3/6/2017    11.24   NA
3/3/2017    10.96   NA
3/2/2017    11.81   NA
3/1/2017    12.54   0.79
```

where I want to let the value of the third column(which has many NAs) from **5/1/2017 to 5/9/2017 to be 0.91, from 4/1/2017 to 4/28/2017 to be 0.9, and from 3/1/2017 to 3/31/2017 to be 0.79.**

How do I write the code to deal with this problem?

Comment: I apologize that the I didn't put the data in the tidy form in the previous version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly simple and more general than doing it in separate segments with the `na.locf` function in pkg:zoo (by "Achim.Zeileis@R-project.org" and @G.Grothendieck, "ggrothendieck@gmail.com"). It has a "fromLast" parameter that starts the process from the end rather than the beginning of a dataframe:

```
> library(zoo)
> dat$V3 <- na.locf(dat$V3, fromLast=TRUE)
> head(dat)
        V1    V2   V3
1 5/9/2017  9.96 0.91
2 5/8/2017  9.77 0.91
3 5/5/2017 10.57 0.91
4 5/4/2017 10.46 0.91
5 5/3/2017 10.68 0.91
6 5/2/2017 10.59 0.91
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the format of `data.frame` is kinda messy and there is no variable names, I am giving hypothesized example here. Suppose the `data.frame` is called `df`, and it has two columns `date` and `value`
You first need to transform `date` into R date.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Then make conditional changes to value like this

```
df$value[is.na(df$value) &
          df$date >= as.Date("5/1/2017",format="%m/%d/%Y") &
           df$date <= as.Date("5/9/2017",format="%m/%d/%Y")] <- 0.91
```

Comment: Hi platypus, if having a data from 1990 to 2017 and have a similar pattern like my dataset, I need to do repeat doing it by myself? or Do I have a better method to solve it?